# Building dropdowns menu with CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm building a dropdowns menu that appears when hovering the mouse over the title. Although I followed some instruction on w3schools, my code doesn't work and I don't know why and how to fix it. All answers is appreciated. Here is my code:

```css
.dropdown {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="menu">
    <h2 class="dropdown">Menu</h2>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Content</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Content</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Content</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Content</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write the hover styles on the wrapper i.e. `<div class="menu">...</div>` because the element `<div class="dropdown-content">...</div>` is a descendant of it.

Also give `display: inline-block;` to the element that is used to open the drop down menu here it is the `<h2 class="dropdown">Menu</h2>` doing so will keep the drop down menu open when the cursor is over it allowing the user to pick an option.

Check the below code snippet.

```css
.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}
.menu:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <h2 class="dropdown">Menu</h2>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Content</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Content</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Content</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Content</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: aha...I got it! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

well a sneaky bug there

```
.dropdown:hover+.dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

`.dropdown` and `.dropdown-content`

they are **siblings** not parent child

indentation of your html is deceiving

Comment: well...the editor make it quite hard to get a perfect indentation...at least for me... Thank you, any way!

Answer (score 0):

Try this [codepen](http://codepen.io/venumadhavdiv/pen/GNBxdb?editors=0100#0)...

Actually what you are doing mistake is you have to show the sibling of your heading on hover what you are doing is`.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}` to apply styles to sibling we have to use `+` like tthis `.dropdown:hover + .dropdown-content {display: block;}`.

hope you understand.